# How to display the AST with SonarSource Language Recognizer?

Tags: sonarqube, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to obtain the same display for my AST and it seems to be possible here : https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/adding-coding-rules/

However, I don't find how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a grammar built with SSLR, you may plug the "toolkit" and run it to display an AST. See how it's done [in sonar-python](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-python/blob/1.14.1.3143/sslr-python-toolkit/src/main/java/org/sonar/python/toolkit/PythonToolkit.java).